# tar --skip-old-files: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Tags: find, tar

I am trying to uncompress all files in a directory. They are are scattered throughout various sub-directories, so I can't just use wildcards. Instead, I used `find`:

```
find . -name "*.tar.gz" -print0 -execdir tar xvf {} \;
```

That worked. However, I wanted to ignore files that were already uncompressed with `--skip-old-files`.

```
find . -name "*.tar.gz" -print0 -execdir tar xvf --skip-old-files {} \;
```

When I add `--skip-old-files`, I get an error for each file:

```
./path/to/file.tar.gztar: --skip-old-files: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Why do I get an error? There must be some minor error that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` expects its argument as the next command-line argument; with

```
tar xvf --skip-old-files {}
```

that’s `--skip-old-files`, which is thus interpreted as the file to be read, not as an option.

Use

```
tar xvf {} --skip-old-files
```

instead.